# MySQL duplicate FK values in myPhpAdmin dropdown list

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

I've built my first ever simple MySQL DB with the myPhpAdmin interface.

1st users table: id (PK), email, fname, lname, isConsultant [bool]...

2nd consultants table: id (PK), title, bio...

3rd table linking both (some users are consultants, some are not): id (PK), user_id (FK), consultant_id (FK).

I have Primary Key and Foreign Key well assigned (I've followed quite a few video tutorials).

Now when I test and try to insert values into my 3rd table, I see "duplicate" options offered to me by the myPhpAdmin interface:

[image: screenshot of the dropdown list of FK values in myPhpAdmin]

[image: myPhpAdmin screenshot of the table structure with PK and index/FKs]

What did I do wrong? Please if you could use simple wordings since I'm new to this!?

Comment: law - 1 is not a duplicate of 1 - law..

Comment: Thx, but why do i get that? I have not seen it on the video tutorials.

Comment: Because both exist in the table.

Comment: 1 = id, Law = value of the title column. That's it. So while there should be '1 - Law' option in the dropdown list, I don't get why I see 'Law - 1' further down too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

phpMyAdmin shows these foreign key relations sorted both ways — by the key and by the referenced name. That makes it easy for you to insert data regardless of whether you know the id is 1 or the corresponding value is Law.

You haven't done anything wrong, and it's a little confusing at first, but this is working exactly as intended. You can use either from the dropdown to pick the same value; it will insert the '1' regardless of whether you select "1 - Law" or "Law - 1".

Comment: Thank you tons Isaac for giving this much needed answer, which even the guys at MySQL forum ('newbie' section) could not even answer properly. You're the best!

Comment: I'm delighted to be able to help you. Thanks for the kind words. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like to me you inputted '1 - Law' as a string to consultant_id, and 'Law - 1' as a string to consultant_id as well, those two strings are not the same, so of course they will not be duplicated....

Comment: Thanks for answering but I did not do that. The consultant table is simple:
ColumnID INT (1, 2...), then Title VARCHAR255 (Law, Biz Dev,...).

Comment: @FredK Ummm when you tried to get the FK from consultant, you somehow combined the two fields, ColumnID and Title into one field?? I think the problem lies in how you combined them??

Comment: @FredK hmmm did you try inserting it and see if it gives you one for both, because it seems strange that you have a string for the input, when your variable is of type int....

Comment: No combined fields. Each columns is well defined. But Isaac Bennetch just gave me the answer, it seems to be normal. So all is good now. Thanks for helping me!